# Are backpacks allowed on Eurolines buses?

Tags: luggage, buses, backpacks

Backpacks are typically less elegant to store in a luggage compartment because of their irregular shape and loose straps. The Eurolines luggage policy reads:

> Unless indicated otherwise in the timetable, the general luggage allowance is two average sized **suitcases** (70x80x20 cm with a maximum total weight of 30 kilos) and one single hand luggage per person. (http://www.eurolines.be/en/luggage)

They don't seem to prohibit backpacks, but they don't explicitly allow them neither.

Does anyone have experience with traveling by backpack on a Eurolines bus?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't work for Eurolines, but I am extremely confident that they allow for backpacks in the hold. Unless your luggage is wildly outside of the stipulated dimensions, like, say, you're transporting a two-seater couch, they will accept pretty much anything.

Bus companies the world over tend to be very lenient with what they accept as hold luggage. Regulations such as the one you point out mostly exist to legally cover the issuer in the unlikely event that, say, everyone brings a two-seater couch.

Answer (score 5):

In 2007, I travelled on Eurolines between Amsterdam and Oslo both ways.  We were a group of 15 young people and all had hiking backpacks in the 60–75 litre range.  It was no problem whatsoever: backpack goes in the luggage compartment under the bus, small items can be brought to the seat in the main part of the bus.

Although my experience is rather old, it would be shocking if backpacks were banned.